# Uncaught TypeError with jquery tablesorter (Rails, Turbolinks)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, tablesorter, turbolinks

I'm experiencing some weird behavior with the Rails app I'm developing.  I'm trying to use the `jquery-tablesorter` gem with mixed success.  Basically, the page I've created keeps giving me the following error in the console after the page lods:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function
(anonymous function) @ VM604:4
m.Callbacks.j @ jquery.min.js:2
m.Callbacks.k.add @ jquery.min.js:2
m.fn.ready @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function) @ VM604:2
executeScriptTags @ turbolinks.js?body=1:227
changePage @ turbolinks.js?body=1:197
xhr.onload @ turbolinks.js?body=1:107
```

The weird thing is that if I refresh the page once it is open and has displayed the error, then everything works fine with no errors in the console.  I'm guessing that somehow the `jquery` libraries aren't loading before the `jquery-tablesorter`. Further more, I suspect that this has something to do with `turbolinks`, because I was getting a similar error before with the `twitter-boostrap-rails` gem, but was able to fix it by reordering my `application.js` file.  But nothing I do seems to fix this error.  Here's the current state of my `application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs  
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-switch
//= require jquery-tablesorter
//= require_tree .
//= require turbolinks
```

Any suggestion to fix the error are appreciated.

Comment: On which Event do you bind tablesorter to the element? Could you provide this code? I made a example which uses turbolinks - maybe this helps: https://github.com/themilkman/tablesorter-demo

Comment: I'm binding it on document ready as follows:

`<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#my_table").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 
    
</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... turns out I had a rogue `<script>` tag at the bottom of one of my pages from when I was trying to play around with Google OAuth Sign-In.  That `<script>` tag was calling an old version of jquery, which conflicted with the version that should have been loading from my `application.js` file.

Anyway, took out the rogue `script` tag, and it fixed everything.  Just for reference this is the final version of the application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-switch
//= require jquery-tablesorter
//= require turbolinks
```

I think other orders might work too, but for now this isn't causing me any problems.